# Swipe not working on first item in the carousel but works after arrow clicked

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap carousel and I have enabled the data-bs-touch to true. The swiping only seems to work after you click the arrow the first time and then the touch/swipe works for every item after that on a mobile view. How do I get the touch to work on the first item in the carousel as well? I am using Bootstrap v5.1.

See below code:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-touch="true" >
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2" class="" aria-current="true"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3" class=""></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555" dy=".3em">First slide</text></svg>

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Second slide</text></svg>

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333" dy=".3em">Third slide</text></svg>

    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/opvL8w4t/

Comment: It's working fine, it's calling the `pointerup` event in the bootstrap js file and works as expected

Comment: The same issue exists in Bootstrap 4.x , the swipe only works for slides 2 to N, but not for the 1st slide. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for a simple answer, and I couldn't find it in any way. in general, the following worked for me (for Bootstrap 5.2):
I just created the variable, after DOM loaded:

```
let x = new bootstrap.Carousel('#myCarousel');
```

and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('carousel')).forEach((x) => new bootstrap.Carousel(x));">
```